# FFMPEG prores_ks 4444 color shift

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, prores

I am attempting to encode "ProRes 4444" movies with ffmpeg.  Some research led me to the "prores_ks" encoder, which is the only one of ffmpeg's prores encoders that supports "4444".

I used this command to test it out (input excluded):

```
-c:v prores_ks -f mov -profile:v 4444 test.mov
```

This produces a ProRes 4444 movie.  However, the colors appear darker than the original input.  After some research I came upon this option:

```
-vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709
```

Adding this filter seems to fix the problem.  However, the file size is for some reason considerably bigger.  Also, I do not like the idea that a filter has to be performed during this encoding, as I want the highest possible quality.  Does anyone know of a way to overcome this "color shift" without a video filter?

Comment: colormatrix filter operates in 8bit only, and you shouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: Also what are input properties, like what colorspace?

Comment: The input is a PNG sequence.

Comment: What bit depth, could you upload one image somewhere?

Comment: I've tried both 8 and 16 bit, out of After Effects.  Here's a PNG and a MOV made with ffmpeg, using command `ffmpeg -r 24 -i colorbars_8bit.png -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 4444 colorbars_prores_ks.mov`: https://file.io/SeKH8I

Comment: Interestingly, Natron's "WriteFFmpeg" module does not seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in how FFMPEG does the RGB->YUV conversion by default.  This option specifies the use of the bt709 color space for the conversion, instead of the default of bt601.  This fixes it for me - though please let me know if I'm doing something bad here!

```
-vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709
```

Comment: 709 is default for HD, 601 for SD.